# How to make correct selection for Cursor android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am rather new in android and SQLite, so please don't be so strict :)

I need to select rows from db, where some String length must be > than 5 symbols.

Here is part of my code:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.start();
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            mUri,
            CONTACT_COLUMNS,
            mSelection, null, null
    );
}
```

So any ideas how my `mSelection` must looks like?

Great thanks for all advises!

Comment: how would it look like in a plane sqlite query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conside you want to check length of column email then query will be

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from user where length(email)>5",null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select particular column eg. NAME of length > 5 , you can do like,

```
String strSelect = "(("+ NAME + " != '' ) AND ("+"length("+NAME+") > 5 ))" ;

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.start();
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            mUri,
            CONTACT_COLUMNS,
            strSelect, null, null
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cursor by using the code given below

1st parameter is distinct

2nd is the name of table

3rd is String array that contains the attribute name that you want to return

4rth one is the where clause

for more details [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29)

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            /* Attributes you want to get seperated by comma */
    }, "length(email)>5", null, null, null, null, null);
```